# I have updated my android studio and change java version (jdk-18.0.2.1). Now I am not able to build my project

Tags: flutter, android-studio

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\xtpl\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\camera_android-0.10.8\android\build.gradle' line: 52
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':camera_android'.

> Could not set unknown property 'baseline' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`your text`